# Rationale for interleaving in G.709

Tags: communication, protocol

According to the [ITU-T G.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.709) (OTN) [specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.709-201202-I/en), a single frame has 4 'rows' and 4080 'columns' of octets, arranged like this:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ... 3824 3825 ... 4080
   +-----------------------------------------+-----+-----------+-------------+
 1 |  frame alignment   |        OTU header  |     |           |             |
   +-----------------------------------------+ OPU |           |             |
 2 |                                         | he- |           |             |
   |                                         | ad- |  payload  |   error     |
 3 |                 ODU header              | er  |           | correction  |
   |                                         |     |           |             |
 4 |                                         |     |           |             |
   +-----------------------------------------+-----+-----------+-------------+
```

The OTU header contains stuff related to transport, and the ODU and OPU headers contain information related to the payload (I don't know the details here).

When the frame is sent, this 2 dimensional representation has to be translated into a (1 dimensional) sequence of octets. Section 11.1 of the specification says that this is done by transmitting all the octets in row 1, then all the octets in row 2, and so on up to row 4.

**Why is the frame transmitted in this order?** To me, it seems easier to transmit the whole header (columns 1-16) all at once, then transmit the entire payload (columns 17-3824), then transmit the error correction (columns 3825-4080). Is there some advantage to interleaving the header, payload, and error correction?

Comment: If the ODU header content in each row is a checksum for the payload in that row, then this arrangement minimizes memory requirements.

Comment: That could be! I actually made a mistake in my ASCII diagram: the error correction is at the right side of the diagram, not in the ODU header. Your comment still makes sense, though.

Comment: another factor is if you have error correction and a burst type of error you want your codes spread out for reconstruction reasons.  If they are all together you can wipe them all out in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks reasonable. The scheme generates four packets, each of which has a header and error-correcting information.

Since the packets have identical size, it is convenient to diagram them as rows.

The problem is your *I don't know the details here*.

You may be assuming that the "2D" areas are monolithic. But perhaps they are decomposable by row. That is to say, for example, perhaps the error correction in row 1 only pertains to the payload of row 1, and isn't just one big block that applies to the payload as a whole.

Comment: The *payload* and *OPU header* sections are monolithic: section 17.6 of the specification says you can put an arbitrary sequence of bytes into it. The *ODU header* section is not monolithic, but its structure does not depend on the structure of the payload.

Comment: You're correct about the error correction of row `i` only depending on columns 1-3824 of row `i` (it's actually split into sixteen 239-byte sub-rows, according to Annex A of the specification). Combining that with The Photon's comment (on the question) produces a plausible explanation.

Answer (score 1):

seems pretty simple to me, Transmission Protocols are generally designed to be able to as error tolerant as appropriate for the situation.

if you transmitted like a file... everything all at once, and there was an error somewhere in the middle it is may be impossible to clean up, or worse the error could go undetected

... but if you have a start sequence, some info about what to expect, some checksum or parity data, then a stop sequence, then you can deal with those transmission units, or packets or atoms (or whatever your protocol refers to them as) as discrete units.

look at anything like TCP, or MPEG-TS and you will find analogous structures.

it is true that this metadata is overhead, but appropriate for the media used... 
Imagine that you could transfer data at 1000 bit/s with a near zero probability for data loss or corruption. Or by pushing things to 10 000 bit/s there is a 1% chance per 10 000 bits that a bit will be lost or corrupted. In that case it would make good sense to develop a transport protocol, even if it had a %50 overhead.